# using sum with join

Tags: php, mysql

I program a site and I can't get this query right.

I have a table that contain the channels

```
select * from `channels`
```

and I have another table that contain the statistics of viewing every page in the site.

To get the all visits to a specific channel I will write

```
SELECT SUM(ip) AS visits FROM `log` where `module` = 'channels' and mid = '15'
```

where 15 is equal the id of a row in the `channels` table.

The query that I need to write should use a join with sum to `select * from channels` and add an extra cell (value) to get the number of visits for every id in Channels.

---

From comments to answers:

> The table called Channels contains columns id and name.  The table called Log contains columns ip, module, mid.  The `log.module = 'channel'`;  `log.mid = channel.id`.  Every channel id (such as '15') can get all of its visits by the query `SELECT SUM(ip) AS visits FROM log where module = 'channels' and mid = '15'`.

Roughly:

```
CREATE TABLE Channels (ID INTEGER, Name CHAR(30), PRIMARY KEY ID);
CREATE TABLE Log (IP CHAR(16), Module CHAR(10), MID INTEGER REFERENCES Channels(ID));
```

Comment: i don't understant join query as well , because of that i tried to make a cell with name of visits that record the visits , but it is not Accuracy , the table of log is more Accuracy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to provide some more information on the tables to get a good answer.  Specifically, you've not explicitly provided information about which column(s) in Channels join with which columns in Visits.  However, with some reading between the lines, a JOIN query with GROUP BY should do the job:

```
SELECT c.id, COUNT(*) AS Visits
  FROM Channels AS C
  JOIN Log      AS L ON c.id = l.mid
 WHERE l.module = 'channels'
 GROUP BY c.id;
```

You can also move the WHERE clause into the ON condition, but the optimizer should do that automatically for you.

If you want to see all Channel records, even those with zero counts, you have to use a LEFT OUTER JOIN (abbreviated LEFT JOIN) and COUNT(x) where `x` is an appropriate column in the Log table:

```
SELECT c.id, COUNT(l.mid) AS Visits
  FROM Channels AS C
  LEFT JOIN Log AS L ON c.id = l.mid
 WHERE l.module = 'channels'
 GROUP BY c.id;
```

Comment: the table of the channel contain id,name
and the table of log contain ip,module,mid
module = channel
mid = channel.id
every channel id can get all of its visits by query 
SELECT SUM(ip) AS visits FROM `log` where `module` = 'channels' and mid = '15'

Comment: @MoustafaAbdulKareem: update the question to include the schemas of both tables.  And, please do that automatically in future.  It is hard to answer questions when the key information is missing (in particular, table names, relevant columns, the primary key and foreign key information).

Answer (score 1):

Since you mention that you're unfamiliar with SQL joins, perhaps you'd find the [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_%28SQL%29) or the [W3Schools lesson](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp) on the subject informative (these were the top 2 results when I searched Google for "SQL join").

Failing that, following the link about `SUM()` in the MySQL [function reference](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/func-op-summary-ref.html) takes one to a page on [`GROUP BY` (Aggregate) functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/group-by-functions.html#function_sum), which is rather a strong hint towards the answer.

```
SELECT channels.*, SUM(ip) AS visits
FROM
  channels JOIN log ON (
    log.module = 'channels' AND
    log.mid = channels.id -- or whatever is the appropriate column in `channels`
  )
GROUP BY log.mid;
```